# Refresh a dropdownlist without reloading the page when adding items to the datasource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a FormView that can update, delete and insert rows into a database.
I use a DropDownList that gets all the ID's from the table and populates the controls of the FormView based on the SelectedValue.

When a new row is inserted into the Table from the FormView I want the ID DropdownList to be updated with the new ID. Similarly, when a row is deleted the deleted ID should be removed from the ID DropDownList. Currently, I accomplish this by calling

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, False)
```

to reload the entire page but I feel like this is not good practice.

What I have tried is putting both the ID DropDownList and FormView into an update panel and using the below code.

```
Protected Sub InsertButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ''Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, False) ''Current Solution
    SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
    IDLookupDDL.DataBind()        
End Sub
```

I also tried the databind inside the itemInserting event.

```
Protected Sub FormView1_ItemInserting(sender As Object, e As FormViewInsertEventArgs) Handles FormView1.ItemInserting        
    SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
    IDLookupDDL.DataBind()        
End Sub
```

Also, I have tried without calling the SqlDataSource.select()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [ItemInserted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.iteminserted(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ItemDeleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.itemdeleted(v=vs.110).aspx) Events of the FormView instead of the ItemInserting one:

```
Protected Sub FormView1_ItemInserted(sender As Object, e As FormViewInsertEventArgs) Handles FormView1.ItemInserted        
    BindIdLookupDatasource()      
End Sub

Protected Sub FormView1_ItemInserted(sender As Object, e As FormViewInsertEventArgs) Handles FormView1.ItemInserted        
    BindIdLookupDatasource()
End Sub

Private Sub BindIdLookupDatasource()
    SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
    IDLookupDDL.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: This was the solution that I needed.